# Java LinkedList previous next

Tags: java, .net, linked-list

is there anything similar to  .Net's 
`LinkedListNode<(Of <(T>)>)..::.Next` and `LinkedListNode<(Of <(T>)>)..::.Previous` properties in Java's `java.util.LinkedList`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the List interface's `listIterator()` method to get a [`ListIterator`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) object. From there you can use the `hasNext()`, `next()`, `hasPrevious()`, and `previous()` methods to navigate the list. Here's a very simple example using `ListIterator`.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

...

List<String> myList = new LinkedList<String>();

myList.add("A");
myList.add("B");
myList.add("C");

...

ListIterator<String> it = myList.listIterator();

if (it.hasNext()) {
    String s1 = it.next();
    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

The example code should print "A".

Answer (score 5):

In general, you don't work directly with the nodes of a `List` in Java. You should probably look into [`ListIterator`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html), an instance of which is accessible via the [`listIterator()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator()) method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `ListIterator` you use that to traverse the List in either direction. The iterator contains methods such as `previous()` and `next()`. [Check it out in the Javadocs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

To get the ListIterator for your current list, call its `listIterator(int index)` method.