# Looping back through string array

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops, counter

So I got this String array that I'm looping through. A rookie question, but, how do I reverse and loop back? Basically what I want is both a "forward" and a "back" function so one doesn't have to loop through the entire array to get back to "a". Thanks!

```
 public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    private static int counter = 0; 
    private TextView exampleTextView;
    string exampleText;


    private static final String[] EXAMPLESTRINGS = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c"
    };

public void generateText(View v) {

    String exampleText = EXAMPLESTRINGS[counter++];
    if( counter == EXAMPLESTRINGS.length ) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    exampleTextView.setText(exampleText);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `counter--`? or just `EXAMPLESTRINGS[0]`? It's a little hard to tell exactly what your problem is or how you expect to implement this. It sounds like you might be thinking an array is sort of like a tape and can only be accessed successively — it's not. You can get any value from an array, not just the "next" one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297110/java-linkedlist-previous-next might help

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the generateText() method is a method that gets called from the UI somehow?
Try something like:

```
public void generateTextForward(View v) {
    if( counter == EXAMPLESTRINGS.length -1 ) {
        counter = 0;
    }
    String exampleText = EXAMPLESTRINGS[counter++];
    exampleTextView.setText(exampleText);
}

public void generateTextBackward(View v) {
    if( counter == 0 ) {
        counter = EXAMPLESTRINGS.length -1;
    }

    String exampleText = EXAMPLESTRINGS[counter--];
    exampleTextView.setText(exampleText);
}
```

And now you have two methods, one for forward and one for backwards. Don't really know the application for this :)

But as some comment above suggested, take a look at a linked list for this instead.

Comment: Exactly, the idea is to have a backwards and a forwards button that deliver the previous/next string in the array. Your code seem to be on the right track, however the behavior is somewhat strange: When executing generateTextBackward, it first goes forward, and only upon executing the function again (and consequent executions) does it go backwards. So starting on "a" it goes "a"-"b"-"a"-"c". Any idea why?